# Transfer data from one textfield to the other without clicking a button

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

I would like my code to display both textfields equal to each other. However, the user can only enter data in textfield `a`. I know this is a pretty easy thing to do by just creating an action button, but I would like the data to be transferred with out hitting a button. So as soon as textfield `a` has something in it the data will be transferred to textfield `b`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var b: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var a: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        fill()
    }

    func fill() {
        if a.text != nil{
            a.text = b.text
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a target to textfield A for the .editingChanged event. You can do this by changing your viewDidLoad to this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    a.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fill), for: .editingChanged)    
}
```